# runit does not start a service

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, runit

I installed `runit-2.1.2` on my ubuntu box,

And, I Created very simple `streaming` service as below,

```
mkdir -p /etc/sv/streaming/
echo 'echo "streaming" >> /var/log/streaming.log' > /etc/sv/streaming/run
```

Then, 
created symlink to `/etc/service/streaming`,

```
ln -s /etc/sv/streaming /etc/service/streaming
```

As, I can see below, symlink is created,

```
root@moby:/# ll /etc/service/streaming
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Dec  2 00:27 /etc/service/streaming -> /etc/sv/streaming/
```

Waited 5 secs, nothing happens.

I also tried manually as below,

```
root@moby:/# sv status /etc/service/streaming     
warning: /etc/service/streaming: unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist
```

I'm using ubuntu 16.04

```
root@moby:/# cat /etc/*release | grep RELEASE
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
```

I feel like `runit` is not running at all.

```
root@moby:/# ps -ef | grep runsvdir
root      1976     7  0 00:58 ?        00:00:00 grep --color=auto runsvdir
```

I don't know the script to start runit either,

```
root@moby:/# service runit start
runit: unrecognized service
```

or

```
root@moby:/# service sv status
sv: unrecognized service
```

Can `runit` users help me know what's going on here?

### Reference

http://smarden.org/runit/install.html

Comment: Why don't you just create a systemd unit for your _real_ service?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well, I am having issue with systemD too. `$ systemctl enable streaming
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory`. Here's my systemD unit - https://gist.github.com/prayagupd/f48900fd7f6b0f9d0a2f840db60469e1#systemd

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the following files, inspired by the configuration for a previously running `runit` server on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

`vagrant@vagrant:/usr/bin$ ls -l runsvdir-start*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 544 Aug 19 05:04 runsvdir-start`

contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin

exec env - PATH=$PATH \
runsvdir -P /etc/service 'log: ...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................'
```

and

`vagrant@vagrant:/usr/bin$ ls -l /lib/systemd/system/runit.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 143 Aug 19 05:07 /lib/systemd/system/runit.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Runit service supervision

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/runsvdir-start
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You may want to confirm paths with `which runsvdir` and this after an `apt-get install runit`.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue on ubuntu 18.04. I was getting the following error while executing "sv status dir_name"

> unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist

The runsvdir is also not showing up in "grep" output. I have solved the issue by installing **runit-systemd** package. Please use the following command to install in ubuntu and debian systems

```
sudo apt install runit-systemd
```

I have found this solution from another askubuntu [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046836/how-to-properly-setup-runit-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I hope this helps